# How can I change my R code so that there are three lines representing data from different blocks? How can I change my code to edit the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, legend

Here is the code I used to produce my figure:

```
Running_Accuracy_Across_Addition %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Trials, y = Accuracy, group = Block, color = Block)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Trials", limits = c("First Ten", "Second Ten", "Third Ten", "Fourth Ten"), labels = c("First Ten" = "5", "Second Ten" = "15", "Third Ten" = "25", "Fourth Ten" = "35")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Proportion of Correct Addition Responses Over 10 Trials", limits = c(0,1.0)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.8) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), text = element_text(family="Times New Roman", size = 12)) +
  labs(title = "Change in Addition Response Accuracy As The Amount of Available Time Reduces", x = "Trials", y = "Proportion of Correct Addition Responses Over 10 Trials")
```

Here is an image of the figure:

[image]

Comment: As a start you could convert the Block variable to a discrete one... Also adding an example data would make it easier for others to help you (add the data in code form, not as table or image. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 1):

Change your grouping variable to factor like this:

```
df$Block <- factor(df$Block)
```

## Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Load example data
data(iris)

# Dummy trials variable
iris$trials <- 1:nrow(iris)
```

### When `color=` is numeric

```
# Plotting behavior for numeric groups
iris$Species_numeric <- as.numeric(iris$Species)
class(iris$Species_numeric)
#> [1] "numeric"

ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_line(aes(trials, Petal.Length, color = Species_numeric))
```

[image]

### When `color=` is a factor

```
# Plotting behavior with factor groups
iris$Species_factor <- factor(iris$Species_numeric)
class(iris$Species_factor)
#> [1] "factor"

ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_line(aes(trials, Petal.Length, color = Species_factor))
```

[image]

Created on 2021-09-28 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)